# No stride function

Tags: list, haskell

I recently needed to *stride* a list in order to peek out only some elements. It’s sorta a *filter* function, but it’s not so simple. But first, here what a stride is.

*Striding* a list – or any traversable type – is the same thing that folding it, but discarding some frequently met elements (regarding the stride value). We pick off an element, then the next value to pick off will be the next stride *th* one. For instance, if we stride a list with a stride value set to 0, we actually get the list unchanged. If we stride 1 a list, we get one element on two:

```
stride 0 [1..10] == [1..10]
stride 1 [1..10] == [1,3,5,7,9]
stride 2 [1..10] == [1,4,7,10]
```

I looked at `Data.List`, I found nothing to `stride` a list. That’s why I’ve written a function to stride my – and your! – stuff:

```
import Data.DList

-- for Data.List
stride :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> [b] -> [b]
stride s = toList . snd . foldl (\(sa,xa) x -> if sa == s then (0,xa `snoc` x) else (sa+1,xa)) (s,fromList [])
```

You can use it like above.
Is it possible to propose it to be part of the `Data.List` module? I think it can help much.

Comment: Why not `stride n xs = chunk (n+1) xs >>= take 1`, using [`chunk` from `Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/latest/doc/html/Data-List-Split-Internals.html#v:chunk)?

Comment: This is *almost* not a question – the only SO-suitable question I can find here is essentially "what's the process to add new functions to standard modules?" and that's buried right at the end.

Comment: The question this answers is rather "how do I stride a list in Haskell".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler implementation that also works on infinite lists and is more efficient would be

```
stride :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
stride s = go
  where
    go (x:xs) = x : go (drop s xs)
    go _      = []
```

If you want it for other types than just `Int`, make it

```
import Data.List

stride :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]
stride s = go
  where
    go (x:xs) = x : go (genericDrop s xs)
    go _      = []
```

Doing it for non-integral types makes no sense IMO.

> Is it possible to propose it to be part of the `Data.List` module?

Yes, that is possible, make a proposal on the libraries@haskell.org mailing list.

I don't think it would be accepted, however. The usefulness is too small to add it to the `base` package. It would be better added to another package. Perhaps including it in [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) would be best.

Comment: Well, it could make sense for `RealFrac`s, basically a more efficient `\s l -> [l!!round x | x<-[0,s..]]` – which wouldn't quite match the example behaviour, though, it would then be `stride 1 ≡ id`, not `stride 0 ≡ id`.

Comment: Something like that might make sense indeed, I didn't think of that. If you look at the linked implementation, it counts up from 0 in steps of 1, until `sa == s`, which only produces more than the initial element if `s` is an integer.

Comment: woah, forgot the `drop` function, great idea :)

Answer (score 3):

This function does not do exactly what you want, but you can base your `stride` function on it:

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n = takeWhile (not . null) . map (take n) . iterate (drop n)
```

Now your stride function might look something like this:

```
stride :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
stride n = map head . chunksOf (n + 1)
```

Using `head` is fine here, because the `takeWhile (not . null)` ensures that a sublist can never be empty.

Comment: Exactly! `chunksOf` is the function that could be added, and `stride` could be based on it.  An alternative implementation of `chunksOf` can be found in this blog post: http://bolo1729.blogspot.com/2011/12/my-first-use-of-state-monad.html

Comment: I'd always say:  go for compositional solutions.  I like this method particularly because of its use of composition.  Neither Daniel's implementation nor yours makes use of that.  Edit: That also makes sure that it's properly lazy.

Comment: Your implementation of `chunksOf` is elegant, no doubt!  It is exactly what I was looking for (and couldn't find, see "future work" remark) when writing my blog post.

Comment: It's an unfoldr! `chunksOf n = takeWhile (not . null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)`

Comment: You can actually implement `stride` itself in terms of `unfoldr` with the following short snippet, but I don't really like it: `stride n = unfoldr (\xs' -> do x:xs <- Just xs'; Just (x, drop n xs))`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively using the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package you can:

```
>stridingOf l n = (elementsOf l ((==0) . (flip mod (n + 1))))
>striding = stridingOf traverse
>stride n = toListOf striding

>stride 1 [1..10]
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

A little bit of extra work of writing stridingOf rather then just striding allows for easy use on text and byteStrings a much more difficult rewrite with out the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package.

```
>import Data.Text
>import Data.Text.Lens

>testText = pack "This is a test"
>toListOf (stridingOf text 1) testText
"Ti sats"
```

#lens